# One-to-many with one-to-one "exceptions"

Tags: database-design

Suppose I have 3 entities: Person, Position and Duration.

I need to be able to assign a duration to each person every day, but it turns out that usually it is the same duration for every person in a position, with perhaps a few exceptions.

So I think I have 2 alternatives:

1. Store one duration for each person each day
2. Make duration to have a `type` field to identify whether it's for a position or a person. Create a duration for each position each day and a duration for each person with different duration than the group

Option 1 seems way simpler, but it might not allow to make edits to duration once it is created since there would be no bookkeeping to manage the "exceptions".

Any thoughts on how to approach this?

In other words, I want to have a one-to-many person-duration relationship (through Position) UNLESS there is a one-to-one duration for the same person on the same day.

If relevant, I'm using Postgres.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just have duration both at the Position and Person level? If Person's duration is NULL, just interpret that as "reuse duration from Position". When you JOIN the two, you can use COALESCE to pick the Position's duration when Person's duration is NULL.

BTW, if your relationship is really one-to-many, you just need a foreign key in Person (referencing Position). Additional junction table would be needed only for a many-to-many relationship.